# Special characters creates problem while writing xml

Tags: java, xml

first of all please excuse my shallow understanding into coding as I am a business analyst. Now my question. I am writing java code to convert a csv into xml. I am able to read csv successfully into objects. However, while writing the xml, when special a space or "=" is encounteredan error is thrown.

Piece of the problematic code, I have imporovised the value in create element just to highlight the problem. In actual I am getting this value from an object:-

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDocument= documentBuilder.newDocument();

Element root = xmlDocument.createElement("Media NationalGroupId="8" AllFTA="1002" AllSTV="1001");

xmlDocument.appendChild(root);
```

---

My xml should look something like this

```
<Media DateCreated="20200224 145251" NationalGroupId="8" AllFTA="1002" AllSTV="1001" AllTV="1000" NextId="1000000">
```

Comment: *error is thrown* is not a problem description unless you include information about what that error is specifically. Generally, a *thrown error* includes an error message, which should be in your post.

Comment: My Bad Ken, here it is
Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. 
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createAttribute(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl.setAttribute(Unknown Source)
 at com.lj.conversion.csvtoxml.readwrite.WriteMediaFile.writeXml(WriteMediaFile.java:36)
 at com.lj.conversion.csvtoxml.runner.RunConversion.main(RunConversion.java:20)

Comment: As a business analyst, you might find this is a lot easier in a high-level language like XSLT or XQuery, rather than grovelling around in the depths of the Java DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createElement should only receive `Media` as the argument.

To add the other attributes (`DateCreated`, `NationalGroupId`, etc), you need to call `setAttribute` on `root`, one by one.

Comment: Element root = xmlDocument.createElement("Media");
root.setAttribute(NationalGroupId, "8");

I did this, still the same error

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. 
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createAttribute(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl.setAttribute(Unknown Source)
 at com.lj.conversion.csvtoxml.readwrite.WriteMediaFile.writeXml(WriteMediaFile.java:36)
 at com.lj.conversion.csvtoxml.runner.RunConversion.main(RunConversion.java:20)